# Нужно использовать массив в 2 пабликах

Tags: c#, массивы, visual-studio

Здравствуйте, столкнулся с проблемой, что нужно использовать массив в двух piblic`ах одновременно, не знаю как это сделать, visual studio не находит массив в другом паблике. язык c#.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int[] kol = new int[listbox.Items.Count];
        int[] price = new int[listbox.Items.Count];
        string[] name = new string[listbox.Items.Count];
        if (listbox.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            listbox.Items.Add(NameBox.Text);

            name[listbox.Items.Count - 1] = NameBox.Text;
            price[listbox.Items.Count - 1] = Convert.ToInt16(Priсe.Value);
            kol[listbox.Items.Count - 1] = Convert.ToInt16(Kol.Value);

        }
    }

    public void listbox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(listbox.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            add.Text = "Добавить";
        }
        else
        {
            add.Text = "Изменить";
            NameBox.Text = name[listbox.SelectedIndex];// выдаёт ошибку, что такого массива нету

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: сделайте эту переменную членом класса

Comment: можно подробней, только учусь программировать

Comment: ответ - ниже, мне, правда, не совсем понятна логика в `add_Click`. Может быть Вам лучше использовать `List<string>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private string[] name;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int[] kol = new int[listbox.Items.Count];
        int[] price = new int[listbox.Items.Count];
        name = new string[listbox.Items.Count]; // use class field, not local variable
        ...
```